# Android - require fingerprint authentication to access (RSA/PSS) signing key

Tags: java, android, authentication, rsa, fingerprint

I'm currently creating a form of challenge-response authentication for a project I need for my Master thesis in computer science.

For this purpose, I need to create an RSA-PSS signature with a private key that is authenticated by a fingerprint so that it can only be used to create a signature when the owner of the device is physically present.

To achieve this, I use the *Android KeyStore* (backed by Keymaster/Gatekeeper in *ARM TrustZone*) to generate an RSA key pair (`KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA`) for use with the RSA-PSS signature algorithm (`SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS`) for creating and verifying signatures (`PURPOSE_SIGN | PURPOSE_VERIFY`). I also require user authentication by setting the corresponding property to `true`.

Later, to create the signature over a buffer `final byte[] message`, I ...

1. obtain an instance of the `FingerprintManager` service
2. create an instance of the `SHA512withRSA/PSS`  signature algorithm (`Signature` object)
3. initialize the `Signature` algorithm for signing with the private key (`initSign(...)`)
4. wrap the `Signature` object into a `CryptoObject`
5. (perform some additional checks)
6. `authenticate(...)` the `CryptoObject` using the instance of `FingerprintManager`, passing (among others) a `FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback` to be called after the key has been authenticated by the user (by touching the fingerprint sensor on his/her device)

Inside the callback, use of the key is authenticated, so I ...

1. extract the `Signature` object from the `CryptoObject` wrapper again
2. use the `update(...)` method on the `Signature` object to stream the data to be signed (`message`) into the signature algorithm
3. use the `sign()` method on the `Signature` object to obtain the signature
4. encode that signature as `Base64` and `println(...)` it out to *StdErr* so it appears in `adb logcat`

I created a sample code which is about as minimal as it gets.

```
package com.example.andre.minimalsignaturetest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

/*
 * Sample code to test generation of RSA signature authenticated by fingerprint.
 */
public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String tag;

    /*
     * Creates a new main activity.
     */
    public MainActivity() {
        this.tag = "MinimalSignatureTest";
    }

    /*
     * Generate a 4096-bit key pair for use with the RSA-PSS signature scheme and store it in Android key store.
     *
     * (This is normally done asynchronously, in its own Thread (AsyncTask), with proper parametrization and error handling.)
     */
    public void generate(final View view) {

        /*
         * Generate RSA key pair.
         */
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("authKey", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY);
            builder.setKeySize(4096);
            builder.setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512);
            builder.setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS);
            builder.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true);
            KeyGenParameterSpec spec = builder.build();
            generator.initialize(spec);
            KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
            PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
            byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
            String publicKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(publicKeyBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            Log.d(this.tag, "Public key: " + publicKeyString);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            Log.d(this.tag, "Key generation failed!", e);
        }

    }

    /*
     * Returns the private key stored in the Android key store.
     */
    private PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {

        /*
         * Fetch private key from key store.
         */
        try {
            KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            store.load(null);
            Enumeration<String> enumeration = store.aliases();
            String alias = null;

            /*
             * Find the last key in the key store.
             */
            while (enumeration.hasMoreElements())
                alias = enumeration.nextElement();

            /*
             * Check if we got a key.
             */
            if (alias == null)
                return null;
            else {
                Key key = store.getKey(alias, null);

                /*
                 * Check if it has a private part associated.
                 */
                if (key instanceof PrivateKey)
                    return (PrivateKey) key;
                else
                    return null;

            }

        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            Log.d(this.tag, "Obtaining private key failed!", e);
            return null;
        }

    }

    /*
     * Create an RSA-PSS signature using a key from the Android key store.
     */
    public void sign(final View view) {
        final byte[] message = new byte[0];
        final PrivateKey privateKey = this.getPrivateKey();
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        FingerprintManager manager = (FingerprintManager)context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

        /*
         * Create RSA signature.
         */
        try {
            Signature rsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA/PSS");
            rsa.initSign(privateKey);

            /*
             * Check if we have a fingerprint manager.
             */
            if (manager == null)
                Log.d(this.tag, "The fingerprint service is unavailable.");
            else {
                FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(rsa);
                CancellationSignal signal = new CancellationSignal();

                /*
                 * Create callback for fingerprint authentication.
                 */
                FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback callback = new FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback() {

                    /*
                     * This is called when access to the private key is granted.
                     */
                    @Override public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
                        FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = result.getCryptoObject();
                        Signature rsa = cryptoObject.getSignature();

                        /*
                         * Sign the message.
                         */
                        try {
                            rsa.update(message);
                            byte[] signature = rsa.sign();
                            String signatureString = Base64.encodeToString(signature, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                            Log.d(tag, "Signature: " + signatureString);
                        } catch (SignatureException e) {
                            Log.d(tag, "Signature creation failed!", e);
                        }

                    }

                };

                /*
                 * Check if we have a fingerprint reader.
                 */
                if (!manager.isHardwareDetected())
                    Log.d(this.tag, "Your device does not have a fingerprint reader.");
                else {

                    /*
                     * Check if fingerprints are enrolled.
                     */
                    if (!manager.hasEnrolledFingerprints())
                        Log.d(this.tag, "Your device does not have fingerprints enrolled.");
                    else
                        manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, signal, 0, callback, null);

                }

            }

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(this.tag, "Signature creation failed!", e);
        }

    }

    /*
     * This is called when the user interface initializes.
     */
    @Override protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

(It's still ~200 LOC long, but fingerprint-authenticated cryptography needs a bit of code to make it work, so I can't seem to get this any smaller/simpler.)

To test it, just create a project with a single activity in *Android Studio*. Insert two buttons into this activity, one for generating a key (i. e. labelled *Generate*) and one for creating a signature (i. e. labelled *Sign*).

Then insert the sample code into your main activity and link the `onclick` events from the *Generate* button to the `public void generate(final View view)` method and from the *Sign* button to the `public void sign(final View view)` method.

Finally, insert the following into your `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside the top-level `<manifest ...> ... </manifest>` tag.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />`

Run the project and let `adb logcat` run alongside it.

After you hit the *Generate* button, you should see an output like this in the logs.

`07-04 14:46:18.475  6759  6759 D MinimalSignatureTest: Public key: MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICC...`

This is the public key of the key pair that has been generated.

(You will also see some complaints about key generation taking place in the main thread, however, this is just to keep the sample code simple. The actual application performs key generation in its own thread.)

Then, first hit *Sign*, then touch the sensor. The following error will occur.

```
keymaster1_device: Update send cmd failed
keymaster1_device: ret: 0
keymaster1_device: resp->status: -30
SoftKeymaster: system/keymaster/openssl_err.cpp, Line 47: error:00000000:invalid library (0):OPENSSL_internal:invalid library (0)
SoftKeymaster: system/keymaster/openssl_err.cpp, Line 88: Openssl error 0, 0
MinimalSignatureTest: java.security.SignatureException: android.security.KeyStoreException: Signature/MAC verification failed
MinimalSignatureTest:   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.engineSign(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:333)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1263)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:649)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at com.example.andre.minimalsignaturetest.MainActivity$1.onAuthenticationSucceeded(MainActivity.java:148)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.sendAuthenticatedSucceeded(FingerprintManager.java:855)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.handleMessage(FingerprintManager.java:803)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
MinimalSignatureTest: Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Signature/MAC verification failed
MinimalSignatureTest:   at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:676)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224)
MinimalSignatureTest:   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.engineSign(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:328)
System.err:     ... 11 more
```

This is where I'm stuck.

The weird thing is that I get `Signature/MAC verification failed` as the message of the `SignatureException`. Note that it says `verification failed`, while I'm actually **signing** (**not** verifying) and the entire stack trace shows, that only *signSomething(...)* functions are called.

I've tried this on the *LG Nexus 5X* with both the official firmware (Android 7.1.1, `N2G47W`) and different (up-to-date) *LineageOS* nightlies and they all fail at this point. However, when I consider the API documentation, it seems as if I'm doing the right stuff, and - to be honest - there's not a lot of stuff you could actually do differently. It actually seems to be pretty obvious how it works.

Note that, as long as I do **not** require user authentication - and therefore don't create the signature in the callback method, but outside, right after the `initSign(...)` - it works fine - even with hardware-backed key storage by Keymaster/Gatekeeper in *TrustZone*. But as soon as I require authentication, - and therefore do the `update(...)` and `sign()` calls on the `Signature` object inside the callback - it all breaks apart.

I tried to trace down the error in the *OpenSSL* library or to find out, what that `-30` response code means, but both to no avail.

Any suggestions? I've gone a long way and implemented a ton of stuff, both server-side and on *Android*, to get this project going forward, but now I'm stuck and seem unable to perform user authentication that's cryptographically sound.

I tried replacing `KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS` with `KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1` and `SHA512withRSA/PSS` with `SHA512withRSA`, then `KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512` with `KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256` and `SHA512withRSA` with `SHA256withRSA`. I also tried a smaller key size - 2048 bit instead of 4096 bit - all to no avail.

I also tried to shift commands from the `initSign(...)`, `update(...)`, `sign()` procedure from the outside of the callback to the inside or the other way round, however, this is the only combination, that's supposed to work. When I move `initSign(...)` inside the callback as well, the call to `authenticate(...)` fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Crypto primitive not initialized`. When I move `update(...)` and `sign()` outside the callback, the call to `sign()` fails with `java.security.SignatureException: Key user not authenticated`. So `initSign(...)` **has** to be outside and `sign()` **has** to be inside. Where `update(...)` happens, *appears* to be uncritical, however, from a semantic point of view, it makes sense to keep it together with the call to `sign()`.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please, instead of referencing the code you are using, post the code.

Comment: Done. (Code is now included in post.)

Comment: I've reviewed a bit your code and I couldnt find any substantial error. I have a similar example working with Nexus, So I suspect it may be an unsupported parameter combination. I suggest you simplify your code and apply a  trial and error process. For example use do not use PSS padding

Comment: It **was**, in fact, an unsupported parameter combination. It just turned out to be **really hard** to find a parametrization that works. Since the constraints do not appear to be documented anywhere, you really have to find this by chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **finally** found a solution.

There were actually **two** problems at hand here.

1. I tried to use *SHA-512* as a mask-generation function for RSA/PSS, which is "probably" unsupported by the cryptographic library that *Android* uses.
2. I tried to sign an empty (0-byte) message, which somehow appears to be "problematic".

When I **both** changed the MGF to *SHA-256* **and** made the message 64 bytes long, signature generation succeeded.

Now, both "requirements" appear to be a bit "weird".

First, you **can** indeed use *SHA-512* as an MGF for RSA/PSS, as long as you *setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)*, so it **has** to be supported by the cryptographic library. It's only when you enable authentication that it suddenly fails and you **have** to fall back to *SHA-256*. I did not perform extensive testing which hash functions work as MGFs for RSA/PSS with authentication and which do not. I just found that *SHA-512* does not work but *SHA-256* does, so the choice of MGF is somehow "restricted" when authentication is enabled.

Second, your message needs to have a certain minimal size in order for it to be signed with authentication enabled. For example, you cannot sign an empty buffer. This makes no sense to me at all since the first step in RSA/PSS is to apply a cryptographic hash function to the message, the output of which is fixed length, so the signature scheme really shouldn't care how long or short the message is, but apparently it does. Like before, I didn't perform extensive testing to find the exact cutoff point where the message becomes "long enough" for signing. However, I found that a 64 byte message can be signed, while an empty (0 byte) message cannot, so the minimal length is somewhere within [1; 64] bytes, both limits inclusive.

Note that, as of now, this seems to be documented nowhere and also the exception thrown is of no use. It just says "signature verification failed" (yes, it says "**verification**" even though we're actually **generating** a signature), so you have no idea that you have to change the MGF and the length of the message to be signed.

Due to this, there might be more to it that I haven't found. I just found this parametrization by "trial and error" and thus have no idea what the actual constraints of the cryptographic library look like.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getPrivateKey` method to:

```
 private PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {

     KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
     store.load(null);

     return (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("authKey", null));
 }
```

In your code, you iterate through all keys and grep the last one, which isn't necessarily the one that you want - or even worse: return `null` if that key doesn't have a private key...

If you want to check whether a key exist:

```
 if (store.containsAlias(keyName)) {
     ...
 }
```