# Authentication error trying to use RSA private key on Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-fingerprint-api

I'm using Xamarin Forms to create an app to sign data.
To access the private key the user must authenticate, since i put this

```
option .SetUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
```

Then i make a call

```
Intent i = keyGuardManager.CreateConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("UAF", "Confirm Identity");
.... 
StartActivityForResult(...)
```

and it enters on

```
OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
```

without any problem after the user authenticates using fingerprint.
However when trying to sign data using

```
sig.Update(byteToSign);
```

it throws the following error:

```
Java.Security.SignatureException: android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated
```

I've already tried authentication with the callback `fingerprintManager.Authenticate`, but the result is the same, it goes to `OnAuthenticationSucceeded` and then throws the same error which makes no sense since, as the method says, the authentication was succeeded.

Couldn't find any help while searching for an answer online.

Comment: [This article has mentioned `KeyStoreException`, please take a look at this](https://q-a-assistant.com/computer-internet-technology/1362847_android-require-fingerprint-authentication-to-access-rsa-pss-signing-key.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That thread is the same as here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908418/android-require-fingerprint-authentication-to-access-rsa-pss-signing-key) and still no solution found... Have no idea what is wrong...